# Си, сортировка таблицы с помощью бинарного поиска

Tags: c, поиск

Подпрограмма создает неупорядоченную таблицу, а нужно, что бы она сразу создавала упорядоченную **с помощью бинарного поиска**.

Входные данные имеют вид: 123dh678 iphone 100

8символов - шифр, название продукта и количество произведенного продукта. Все это в main читается из файла и добавляется в таблицу. current_num_tables - количество элементов в таблице.

```
struct table
{
char code[9];
char name[255];
int numb;
};
```

Упорядочить думаю будет лучше и легче всего по numb (количество произведенного продукта)

Как я понимаю, нужно с помощью бинарного поиска определять индекс элемента, и вставлять его по индексу в массив. Если место для вставки этого элемента не пусто, то нужно сдвинуть все элементы до индекса на -1.

В общем, убрал подпрограмму table_add и вставляю сразу с помощью бинарного поиска при чтении из файла.

Работает правильно, но при совпадении (если code будет одинаковым, например th00tf00 apple 1 th00tf00 apple 50, то в таблице должно быть только th00tf00 apple 51, а появляется th00tf00 apple 51 th00tf00 apple 50)

```
while (fscanf(f, "%s %s %i", code, name, &numb) != EOF && current_num_tables < N)
{
    int pos = insert(numb, t, &current_num_tables);
    for (int i = 0; i < current_num_tables; ++i)
    {
        if (!strcmp(code, t[i].code))
        {
            t[i].numb += numb;
        }
    }
    strcpy(t[pos].code, code);
    strcpy(t[pos].name, name);
}
```

Вот так работает, но без учета совпадений.

```
while (fscanf(f, "%s %s %i", code, name, &numb) != EOF && current_num_tables < N)
{
    int pos = insert(numb, t, &current_num_tables);
    strcpy(t[pos].code, code);
    strcpy(t[pos].name, name);
}

static int insert(size_t value, struct table *array, int *length)
{

int first = 0;
int last = *length - 1;
int pos = -1;

if (*length == 0)
{
    array[0].numb = value;
    ++(*length);
    return 0;
}

while (first <= last) {

    int i = first + (last - first) / 2;

    if (value < array[i].numb) {
        last = i - 1;
    }
    else if (value > array[i].numb) {
        first = i + 1;
    }
    else {
        pos = i;
        break;
    }
}
if (pos < 0) {
    pos = first;
}

// Подвигаем хвост массива, чтобы освободить место под элемент.
memmove(array + pos + 1, array + pos, (size_t)(*length - pos) * sizeof(array[0].numb));

array[pos].numb = value;

++(*length);

return pos;
}
```

Comment: может вы имете в виду [метод вставки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Comment: Бинарный поиск подразумевает использование уже отсортированного массива. С помощью него не отсортировать

Comment: В чем проблема с приведенным кодом? Можете привести пример входа, на котором он выдает некорректный результат?

Comment: @defaultlocale исправил большое количество кода и привел пример, на котором он не работает и почему, только не понимаю, как исправить это

Answer (score 3):

В функцию бинарного поиска вы должны передать указатель на массив структур, в который собираетесь что-то вставить, то есть

```
int binarysearch(int value_for_insert, struct table* t, int max_size)
{
/* ... */
}
```

Дословно:

```
int binarysearch(<что>, <куда>, <доколе>)
```

А "препод" не принимает ваш вариант не из-за этого, а скорее из-за того, что у вас по ошибке на строку, причем ошибки смысловые.

В функции `add_table` вы оставили поиск по `code` в уже **отсортированную** по полю `numb` таблице.

Что получается? Вы первый элемент вставляете нормально, еще парочку возможно тоже, имеете сортированную по `numb` таблицу, а затем приходит элемент с таким же `code`, и вы без всякого бинарного поиска втыкаете `+numb` в некий элемент, и ломаете свою сортированную таблицу, после чего бинарный поиск становится бесполезен - таблица то не упорядочена больше.

Решение: вставка элементов должна идти только по алгоритму бинарного поиска, что гарантирует всегда отсортированную таблицу. Если вам нужно добавить значение `numb` к элементу с таким же `code` - вы **обязаны** вынуть этот элемент из таблицы, изменить его, а только потом вставить обратно тем же бинарным поиском. Тогда алгоритмически будет все правильно, дело за реализацией.

Вторая явная ошибка здесь - сдвиг элементов. У вас же элемент - это структура, почему вы присваиваете в цикле только поле `numb`? Это как иметь список сотрудников с зарплатой N рублей, а при увольнении сотрудника его зарплата переходит предыдущему сотруднику по алфавиту. При найме вы получаете зарплату следующего по списку. Вы бы стали работать старшим менеджером за зарплату грузчика?

Посмотрите:

```
for (i = 1; i < index; i++)
{
    t[i].numb = t[i - 1].numb;
}
```

Решение: замените на перенос структуры через [memcpy](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcpy) (подразумевается, что размер одного блока равен `sizeof(*t)` и не содержит динамических данных вроде указателей и т.д., иначе их нужно корректно клонировать):

```
for (i = 1; i < index; i++)
{
    /* void *memcpy(void *dst, const void *src, size_t n); */
    memcpy(t[i], t[i - 1], sizeof(*t));
}
```

Третий вопрос возникает сам собой, если посмотреть на код:

```
/* Куда сохраняется результат вызова 'binarysearch()'?
   По коду функции результат равен -1 в случае ошибки или индексу в массиве для сдвига и вставки */
binarysearch(_numb, ??? , current_num_tables);
/* Чему равно значение 'index' здесь, и какой в нем смысл? */
if (t[index].numb != NULL)
    for (i = 1; i < index; i++)
    {
        t[i].numb = t[i - 1].numb;
    }
/* Выше происходит сдвиг элементов (возможно, для освобождения места для нового элемента?). Ниже - увеличивается размер таблицы. А где вставка элемента, индекс которого мы получили в бинарном поиске, и для которого освобождали место? Зачем мы проводили этот бинарный поиск, если не используем его результат? */
current_num_tables++;
return;
```

Решение: нарисовать на бумажке таблицу, ее устройство и действия программы. Лучше таких рисунков сделать штук 5-6, для разных состояний таблицы (пустая, 3 элемента, 10 элементов, вставка в начало, в середину, в конец). Это позволит вам понять, что происходит.

Как видите, вопросов к коду больше, чем ответов на ваш изначальный вопрос. Это нормально. Мой вам совет - напишите по шагам сначала алгоритм (простым русским языком, на листочке), осмыслите его, представьте, что это не код программы, а вы сами будете его выполнять - и тогда вам станет понятно, каким должен быть код.

Удачи )

Comment: Ахах, столько ошибок из за того, что я просто взял подпрограмму добавления из своей предыдущей версии программы, реализованной на пузырьковой сортировке, в ней не было ошибок и она идеально работала. Вот её "препод" не принял. Если бы я сдал то, что написал в посте, то у меня скорее всего больше не было бы препода))

Comment: Вы уверены, что следует использовать `memcpy` ?  Аргумент типа `struct table` несовместим с параметром типа `const void*`.

Comment: Вы правы, именно поэтому мы передаем не сам `struct table`, а указатель на него, сдвинутый на i и i-1 соответственно. В параметр `binarysearch()` мы же передаем `struct table* t`, указатель на тип, правильно? А к `const void*` можно привести любой указатель, собственно для этого `void*` и существует

Comment: А почему тогда не компилится? Выдает ошибку из за `memcpy(t[i], t[i - 1], sizeof(*t));`

Comment: Какой компилятор и какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: VS 2015 memcpy: фактический параметр не является указателем + аргумент типа "struct table" несовместим с параметром типа "const void *" + аргумент типа "struct table" несовместим с параметром типа " void *"

Comment: Попробуйте сначала так: `memcpy(&t[i], &t[i - 1], sizeof(*t));`. Если не прокатит и будет ругаться на несоответствие типов, ударьте его по башке `memcpy((void*)&t[i], (const void*)&t[i - 1], sizeof(*t));`. Просто если вы пишете на VS 2015, там может прокатывать и присвоение структур. Попробуйте также просто присвоить `t[i] = t[i-1];`, посмотрите что скажет. Я пишу на ANSI C99, да еще и не под x86, а под всякие встренные процессоры и архитектуры, язык тот же, а вот компиляторы и их настройки - разные.

Comment: `memcpy(&t[i], &t[i - 1], sizeof(*t));` сработало. Но появилась другая ошибка. В строчках `if (a < t[middle])` и `else if (a > t[middle])` : 
Ошибка (активно)  выражение должно иметь арифметический тип. Ругается типо `>` `<` недопустимо для `struct`. :( Это нормально?

Comment: Ну странно сравнивать структуры, если вы должны сортировать таблицу по одному полю. Возьмите это поле от обоих структур и сравнивайте. Очевидно же )

Comment: Да, очень глупая была ошибка)) В общем я исправил функцию добавления, теперь выглядит немного пологичней, но все равно бредово.

Comment: @alexandr, посмотрите внимательно на свою реализацию функции `insert()`, конкретно на действия при условии больше или меньше. Вы уверены, что сдвигая на +1 и -1 индексы, получаете алгоритм бинарного поиска? Почитайте внимательнее описание самого алгоритма, что он должен делать: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA